# Tree algorithm for getting a list of descendant users

Tags: php, algorithm, symfony, sorting, tree

I'm trying to get a list of descendant users from a user up to 5 levels.

The function should return an array of 5 levels, inside each of those arrays there is a list of users.

Example: 
[image: Example]

I've written something already and it seems to works well but it also seems that performance-wise this is somewhat of a bottleneck:

Note: *getDescendantsForUser* returns a User array which contains [id, name, parent_id] for each one, the function should be initialized with $oUser only.

```
public function getTotalDescendantRecursive(User $oUser, &$level = -1, &$oDescendants = null, &$oPreviousDescendants = null)
{
    if ($level == 6){
        return $oDescendants;
    }

    $oNewDescendants = $this->getDescendantsForUser($oUser);

    if ($oDescendants == null) {
        $oDescendants = array([],[],[],[],[],[]);
        $oDescendants[0] = $oNewDescendants;
    }
    elseif ($oPreviousDescendants != null) {
        // As "array_unique(array_merge..." doesn't work here, we have to check this manually
        $pointerToDescendantsOnLevel = &$oDescendants[$level];
        foreach ($oPreviousDescendants as $key => $value) {
            if (!in_array($value, $pointerToDescendantsOnLevel)) {
                array_push($pointerToDescendantsOnLevel, $value);
            }
        }
        unset($oPreviousDescendants); 
    }

    $level++;

    foreach ($oNewDescendants as $key => $val) {
        $oNewNewDescendants = $this->getTotalDescendantRecursive($val, $level, $oDescendants, $oNewDescendants);
    }

    if ($level != 0) {
        $level--;
    }

    return $oDescendants;
}
```

**How would you optimize this?**

Thanks in advance!